# How to download Windows Defender Antivirus Definition updates programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, antivirus, windows-defender

My client has more than 1000 machines with Windows 10 IOT Enterprise 2016 OS in them. None of the machines are connected to internet. Client wants me write a service which can download Windows Defender Definition Updates (which is mpam-fe.exe) and using FTP this update file can be transferred to IOT machines. Once the transfer is done, IOT machine will install the update automatically. I was wondering is there any way to download the Windows Defender Definition Updates programmatically?

Comment: I think you would normally do this with Windows Updates, WSUS and group policy

Comment: Powershell has a command for this called Update-MpSignature, which also has a command for -UpdateSource, if WSUS and group policy are not an option (They should be your first option) you could through powershell remoting execute the commands above to pull definition updates from a share the machines have access too.  Here is a link to the command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/update-mpsignature?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 0):

Download them with a PowerShell script:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=arm" -OutFile "C:/mpam-fe.exe"
```

Select the right link here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/definitions

Then you can change `C:/` to the FTP folder.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I cant use the Microsoft link as it or its format can change anytime after the deployment.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with any internet request. You must explain your customer, that's even simple service requires support.